# Display Block in Category List

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, color-swatches

I need to display below file in my category list page as a block

```
frontend\default\theme_name\template\configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml
```

`Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Configurable_Swatches`

Is it possible??

**------------------------------------Edit----------------------------------------------**

In my Product View, the swatches are displaying like

[image: product options in product view page]

But in Category Page i'm using a Quick view option where the product option is

[image]

How can i display the same in product category also?

**configurableswatches.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">

        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/script.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/configurableswatches.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>

<product_list>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-list.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list.name.after">
        <block type="core/template" name="product_list.swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list.after">
        <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_media_js_list" name="configurableswatches.media.js.list" />
    </reference>
</product_list>

<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="product_list"/>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="product_list"/>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <update handle="product_list"/>
</catalogsearch_result_index>

<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <update handle="product_list"/>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.media">
        <action method="setGalleryFilterHelper"><helper>configurableswatches/productimg</helper></action>
        <action method="setGalleryFilterMethod"><method>filterImageInGallery</method></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.media.after">
        <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_media_js_product" name="configurableswatches.media.js.product" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers">
        <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_product_view_type_configurable_swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.configurable.after">
        <block type="core/template" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/swatch-js.phtml" />
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it in category page? If you look at that module you will notice that such block is used in configurable products view. Look for this file: `configurableswatches.xml`.

So I'm not sure if you will get success to print it out in category page.

Still, in order to test. Have you tried to add the block to the layout under the handle **catalog_category_default** or **catalog_category_layered**

Make a reference to **content** and add something like:

```
<block type="configurableswatches/catalog_product_view_type_configurable_swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml" />
```

this is a copy 'n paste from previous mentioned file at:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/configurableswatches.xml
```

EDIT:

Can you try to install a clean magento, I did yesterday with latest CE v1.9 and installed also sample data and searched for product: "ELIZABETH KNIT TOP". There were swatches in the listing. Is that what you need? Could you try to reproduce the same I did and confirm.

If it is like so, then you have your solution there, if it is not your desired result, I think I can not help you any more. Sorry.

Comment: I just updated my question with exact details please check.

Comment: Have you checked the file: configurableswatches.xml. In magento-1.9-CE I can see some suggesting code, handle "product_list", is this not working for you? or usable at all in your case? I edited answer with file path.

Comment: I'm using `<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </span>`          to display the swatches in product view page, but it's not working in product category page. I'm also attaching my configurableswatch.xml in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what do you want to do anymore. Yesterday I installed a clean magento latest v1.9 CE, with the sample data. There are swatches in the product list, category and search pages. See the updated answer please.